# Methods may access private instance variables of objects in their own class?

Tags: java

I am reading a book and it states that methods may access private instance variables of objects in their own class. Here is the method that they do it in:

```
public static double distance(Location p1, Location p2)
{
    double a, b, c_squared;

    if((p1 == null) || (p2 == null))
        return Double.NaN;

    a = p1.x - p2.x;
    b = p1.y - p2.y;

    c_squared = a*a + b*b;
    return Math.sqrt(c_squared);
}
```

The part that I am having trouble understanding is why it can access the private instance variables of p1 and p2 like this (assume they are private in the implementation). Is there a special rule when it comes to static methods that make it so they can access private variables or something? Just to clarify.. this static method is from the Location class.

Comment: Can you plz share Location ?

Comment: I get it now. I see that private variables can be used with any method of the class, regardless if it is an instance or not. Thank you.